# Generate install4j application launcher, that executes batch file

Tags: java, windows, install4j

I have a legacy Batch-File that starts up my application after doing some configuration. Trying to migrate to install4j i ran into the problem, that i cannot generate a launcher that only executes the batch file and gives me all the perks a generated launcher would offer.

The current (pretty ugly tbh) workaround is to package a separate executable jar that wraps the execution of the script and can be used by install4j to generate the launcher.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript " + BOOTSTRAP_SCRIPT);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this with install4j without wrapping the script call?

EDIT:
I ended up using the current workaround. The solution in the accepted answer works, but i couldn't get a launcher with integrated auto-update functionality to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom installer application instead of a generated launcher. Under "Installer->Screens & actions", add an empty installer application and to its startup node add a "Run executable" action that starts the batch script.